# Refactoring duplicated code in Angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, refactoring

I need to refactor duplicated code but I don't know how I would do it.

I have two methods that basically call the same service (I need to call the same request because of pagination) but now it looks ugly because of duplicated code. How can I make this better?

```
    getStockData(id: string): Observable<{
    searchResult: IStockResult[];
    searchCount: number;
}> {
    return this.service
        .search(
            id,
            this.service.getSearchMetaDefaults()
        )
        .pipe(
            map(response => {
                return {
                    searchResult: response, 
                    searchCount: response.meta.totalResourceCount
                };
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly multiple elegant solutions to the question. I could propose the following quick changes

1. Define types for the objects used (eg. using TS interface)

```js
export interface ISearch { 
  searchResult: IStockResult[]; 
  searchCount: number; 
}

export interface IMeta {
  pagination: {
    size: number;
    index: number;
  },
  sorting: {
    order: string;
    attribute: string;
  }
}
```

2. Define [optional parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) using `?:` and send the argument as object using the types defined.

```js
getData(id: string, meta?: IMeta): Observable<ISearch>
```

So the previous calls would change to

```js
getStockData('some id') -> getData('some id')
```

```js
paginate(1, 3, 'some id', 'some order', 'some attr') ->

const meta: IMeta = {
  pagination: {
    size: 3,
    index: 1
  },
  sorting: {
    order: 'some order',
    attribute: StockMapper.getDataForSorting('some attr')
  }
};

getData('some id', meta);
```

3. Check if the optional argument is defined using [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) before using it.

```js
const meta = meta ?? this.service.getSearchMetaDefaults();
```

Combining everything

```js
getData(id: string, meta?: IMeta): Observable<ISearch> {
  const meta = meta ?? this.service.getSearchMetaDefaults();

  return this.service.search(id, meta).pipe(
    map(response => ({
      searchResult: StockMapper.fromStockResource(response),
      searchCount: response.meta.totalResourceCount
    } as ISearch))
  );
}
```